# How to run data comparison on tables with different names in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I have two linked sql servers (server A and server B). On A I have database X that contains a table with the name Images. On server B I have database Y with a table called REPL_Images that is suppose to automatically replicate whats in the Images table from Server A. I have discovered that data is missing from the REPL_Images table. When I open Visual Studio and use the data comparison and synchronization tool, I select ServerA.X as the source and ServerB.Y as the target. But when I go to the next screen and expand tables, the Images table isn't even listed. I assume it is because the tables have different names (I did not create the schema). Is there a way to force a comparison AND synchronization between two tables of your choosing no matter what?

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not solve your issue?

Comment: All I have been able to find is A) details on the differences between the two tables, but no synchronization (which I can do myself with a query), and B) This product cost money. So why not tell me what you know (if you know anything that is) instead of interrogating me? what have you researched, tried, and found regarding this issue? Sitting there and making sure someone has met your standards before helping, lovely. I have only asked two questions on here because I am that good at finding what I need. So before assuming, how about you do your due diligence?

Comment: That's quite the demeanor you have there.

Comment: If you can do synchronisation yourself with a query, why not use that method to find the differences between the tables? Basically the tables need a join key, then you  just full outer join on that to find missing records.